# Manipulating spacing in a text object

Tags: graphics, text, spacing

I want to visually illustrate substitution in a mathematical expression.  This is an example:

```
Graphics[Text[
  Style[3 x^2 + 2 (1 + y) // TraditionalForm, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
   24], {0, 0}], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-.2, .2}}]
```

I would like to replace the `y` by `15`, then replace `1 + 15` by `16`, each time moving the characters in the text box to have proper typographical spacing.  (Eventually I want to make the parentheses vanish as well, but never mind that now.)  What I want to do is manipulate the spacing by operating on the text box, not by evaluating `3x^3 +2(1+15)`.  This would seem to require accessing the location in the text box of each character.  I can't find anything in the documentation that shows how to do this.

If you use `ToBoxes` on something generated by `TreeForm` you CAN see the locations of the nodes (although they are buried in a big mess of detail), but `ToBoxes` doesn't do that in the case of formulas as text.

Comment: I edited your post to format the code (indent 4 spaces), and put the `Arial` in quotation marks because otherwise you get `Helvetica`.

Comment: When you say "visually illustrate" - do you mean to make an animation? That's the interpretation I used in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

To "manipulate spacing in a text object" one can use [`AdjustmentBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AdjustmentBox.html). For example, the first step in your visualization could be something like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Text[DisplayForm[ToBoxes[
      Style[3 x^2 + 2 (1 + y) // TraditionalForm, 
       FontFamily -> "Arial", 24]
      ] /. "y" -> AdjustmentBox["y", BoxMargins :> d]], {0, 0}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-.3, .3}}],
 {d, 0, 1}]
```

[image: adjustmentbox]

Of course I'm not sure to what extent you want to animate things, so I just used a `Manipulate` to show the effect. The main point is that I picked out the variable `"y"` as it appears in the box form of the formula, then post-processed it by making a substitution that surrounds the `"y"` by `AdjustmentBox["y", BoxMargins :> d]`. Here, `d` is the extra space that you'd need to create before replacing the `y` by `15`.

The space is given by `BoxMargins` - if you want to create *only* horizontal space, you'd use `BoxMargins :> {{d, d}, {0, 0}}`.

Comment: That is going to be very useful for what I want to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Perhaps you are not aware of `HoldForm`:

```
Graphics[Text[
  Style[3 x^2 + 2 (1 + 15) // HoldForm // TraditionalForm, 
   FontFamily -> "Arial", 24], {0, 0}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-.2, .2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If this is not what you're after perhaps you could add an explanation of why this is not appropriate.

Comment: I did not know about HoldForm.  Thanks.